# Pandas string tokeniztion too slow

Tags: python, pandas, token

I have a column in a Pandas DataFrame, where each row has some string containing a job description like `'senior data consultant'`, and there are approximately 1,000,000 of these rows. I want to shorten this string to just the first word (which in that example would give `'senior'`). The code below does this without error.

```py
def proc_Profession(df):
    for row in range(df['Profession'].size):
        try:
            df['Profession'].iloc[row] = df['Profession'].iloc[row].split(' ')[0]
        except AttributeError:
            df['Profession'].iloc[row] = 'unknown'
    return df
```

The problem that I have is that this is too slow (it takes several hours), is there a faster way of doing this?

Comment: Can't just use `df["Profession"].str.split().str[0]`?

Comment: Yes exactly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As per [Henry Yik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9284423/henry-yik)'s suggestion, the following is significantly faster

```py
def proc_Profession(df):
    df['Profession'] = df['Profession'].str.split().str[0]
    return df
```